# Jquery Validation require 2 exact value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use jquery validation for my form and I need to set exact length to my input "6 or 13".

I tried to catch length of input and manually show error, problem is that if input is not valid, my manually inserted error and jquery validator error show in one row. Then I tried to empty my custom error on `keypress` and on input `change`, but it hides my custom error if i click on screen or use different action.

here is my code:

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

$().ready(function() {
  $("#My_Form_ID").validate({
    rules: {
      anyID: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 6,
        maxlength: 13
      }
    },
    messages: {
      anyID: {
        required: "Some text",
        minlength: "Some text"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="anyID" maxlength="13">
```

Comment: You must have a `name` attribute on the field and this name is used as the identifier used within the `rules` object for `.validate()`, NOT the `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add your custom validation method like I did in below example.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" id="field" name="field">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
jQuery.validator.addMethod("len6or13", function(element) {
  return element.length==6 || element.length==13 ? true : false;
}, jQuery.validator.format("Input data must be 6 or 13 characters long"));
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      len6or13: true
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, you may simply ignore this field by specifying field selector and process that field on your own, like so:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  ignore: ".ignore"
});
```

Comment: With custom validation method you can go even further and request as a parameter acceptable string lengths in form of array and perform checking current input length against that array.

Comment: Yes, I also did that and wanted to add answer, but u did it first!) Thank you for your answer)